# Android: How to hide/remove the taskbar

Tags: android

i'm using the code below and it doesn't work. i don't know why. please help.

```
public class FullScreen extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you checked this link: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

Comment: declare it in manifest file... it will work

Answer (score 0):

To hide Action bar simply use -

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); 
actionBar.hide();
```

To hide status bar add this to your activity tag in manifest -

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in the manifest file:

```
   <activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should type in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName" 
android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```